# Where can I find documented details of virus so that I might be able to find out why I am infected?

Tags: virus

My AV detected that some computers in our network are infected with Win32.Sality.Y. 
Is there any good place I can find the documented details of this virus, so that I can (generally) how the virus works. Then I might be about to find out if it's infected via browser, or email, or USB stick, or other ways.

Answer (score 1):

Google's your best bet. Sality is/was a pretty large botnet, so there's loads of info out there:

- [Sality on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sality)
- [Microsoft Malware Protection Center](http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/Threat/Encyclopedia/Entry.aspx?name=Virus%3aWin32/Sality.AT)
- [Symantec's knowledge base](http://www.symantec.com/security_response/writeup.jsp?docid=2007-031607-5450-99)

You likely got it from a shared drive or an infected USB stick, which is its main propagation method.